# How to show another text if field val 0?

Tags: theming, 8

```
{% for item in items %}
    {% if item.content %}
        <div class="result-features__body">
            <p class="result-features__title">balance</p>
            <p>Yes {{ item.content }}</p>
        </div>
    {% else %}
        <div class="result-features__body">
            <p class="result-features__title">balance</p>
            <p>Nope</p>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

My field is integer.
I try all if (is null, is same as, etc...) but nothing works.

Comment: do you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK  this is the correct way:

```
{% for item in items %}
    {% if item.content == 0 %}
        <div class="result-features__body">
            <p class="result-features__title">balance</p>
            <p>Yes {{ item.content }}</p>
        </div>
    {% else %}
        <div class="result-features__body">
            <p class="result-features__title">balance</p>
            <p>Nope</p>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```